# Dockerised local Squid proxy gives 5xx errors to some requests done with Axios but works with others

Tags: squid

I'm trying to set up a local Squid proxy which does not cache anything. I am using Dockerised squid based on this image:
https://hub.docker.com/r/ubuntu/squid

I run the image like so:

```
docker run -d --name squid-container -v /host/squid.conf:/etc/squid/squid.conf -e TZ=UTC -p 3128:3128 ubuntu/squid:4.13-21.10_edge
```

And I am now testing it via Node application with Axios like that:

```
  const res = await axios.get('https://www.google.com', {
    proxy: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3128
    }
  });
  console.log(res.data);
```

It does not work. For the Google example it responds with HTTP 502 for example and in Squid logs I can see:

```
1646472971.202    183 172.17.0.1 TCP_MISS/502 3904 GET https://www.google.com/ - HIER_DIRECT/216.58.209.196 text/html
```

But for some requests it does work. For example `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmTWMcWKgv2a5GjH6GoUjJXChZ55HAE3tVEXvPzpdbMnFU/102` works fine.

My Squid configuration (Some of the stuff put there is already gotten from researching this problem but none of them helped. Caching is intentionally turned off)

```
cache deny all
dns_v4_first on
forwarded_for off
via off
http_access allow all
acl all src all
```

The HTML page I get on error from Axios is:

```
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: https://www.google.com/

Read Error

The system returned: [No Error]

An error condition occurred while reading data from the network. Please retry your request.

Your cache administrator is webmaster.
```

Without using the proxy, all the axios requests work. Does anyone know why some requests work and some don't?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be Axios issue not Squid configuration problem. With `curl --proxy ...` everything works like a charm. Found this ticket:

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/658

Since I am not tied to Axios, I will use a different library. Hopefully this helps someone, as I spent way too much time on this.